# Libgdx ScreenManager

Tags: java, libgdx

I am working on a game in LibGdx and I will be switching screens a lot so I thought I'd make my own little screen manager. However to set a screen I need to reference `LibGdx Game`. I am not happy with how the manager looks right now, there must be some way I can achieve this without having to send a Game object twice.

My code:

```
public static void setScreen(Screen screen, Game game){
        if(currentScreen != null){
            currentScreen.dispose();
            System.out.println("Screen disposed");
        }
        currentScreen = screen;
        game.setScreen(currentScreen);
    }
```

Now to set a screen from another screen (for example to set gameScreen from menuScreen) Id need to send a game object to the constructor of the screen, like this:

`ScreenManager.setScreen(new GameScreen(game), game);`

The perfectionist in me want to be able to call it like this:

`ScreenManager.setScreen(new GameScreen(), game`

or

`ScreenManager.setScreen(new GameScreen(game)`

Can anyone think of a way to do this? Or am I just obsessing over something that I might as well let be?

Comment: Does `SceneManager` have to be a singleton? One possible solution might be to allow instancing of it, and pass in your `Game` object in the constructor, though something still feels off about that...

Comment: One more comment, because I've been in a similar situation. It looks like you're developing a knot of dependencies where (I assume) the game depends on the scene manager, and the scene manager depends on the game. Try and make it go just one way, e.g. the game tells the manager to update and render, and the manager tells the current scene to update and render.

Comment: Thanks for your comments :) This is actually the only method in ScreenManager. I dont do any rendering or anything like that. I just set the screen and dispose of the old one. I have thought about creating my own abstract Screen class instead of implementing the one in LibGdx. Maybe I will do that, and I wont have to reference `Game`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create your own Screen type which will return the game in it and will implement Screen methods.

```
package ***;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import ***.GameCore;

public class MyScreen implements Screen {
    GameCore game;
    public MyScreen(GameCore game) {
        this.game = game;
    }

    public GameCore getGameCore(){
        return this.game;
    }
    /*
    Methods implemented from Screen (render , hide , dispose etc...)
    */
}
```

And then create your screen types which will extend MyScreen.

```
package ***;

import ***.GameCore;

public class MenuScreen extends MyScreen{

    public MenuScreen (GameCore game) {
        super(game);        
    }
    /*
    Methods implemented from Screen (render , hide , dispose etc...)
    */
}
```

Create an instance of MenuScreen in GameCore.

```
MenuScreen menuScreen = new MenuScreen(this);
```

And after that you can do the trick you want .

```
public static void setScreen(Screen screen){
    if(currentScreen != null){
        currentScreen.dispose();
        System.out.println("Screen disposed");
    }
    currentScreen = screen;
    currentScreen.getGameCore().setScreen(currentScreen);
}
```

Then you can freely set your screens in the way

```
ScreenManager.setScreen(new MenuScreen(game));
```

or

```
ScreenManager.setScreen(menuScreen);//if you have already created an instance of menu
```

Answer (score 2):

I've implemented my own `ScreenManager` by also implementing my own `Screen` which  extends `Group`. The protocol I use is designed for minimum object instantiation:

- All `Screen` objects should be singletons. I made their constructors package-private and only the `ScreenManager` can directly instantiate them. They are stored in a hash map.
- Only instantiate your `Screen`'s objects once, at instantiation time, and add them to the `Screen` (all my components are therefore also extending `Actor`).
- Implement a method `getInputProcessors()` that returns any custom handlers used by the custom `Screen` that will not be implicitly triggered by the stage. (I actually have a similar set of functions for other objects, but removed here for clarity.)
- My `ScreenManager` calls `show` and `hide` when a screen needs to be swapped out, which don't actually need to do anything but can be overridden for custom behavior.

The way this works underneath, is that my ScreenManager has a `Stage`. The manager simply clears the stage object between screens and adds the new stage, since it is a `Group` (which is an `Actor` that can contain more actors).

Without going into too much detail, which would involve explaining lots of internal classes in my framework, here is the general procedure with functionality abstracted away that may not be relevant to you (and allowing external Screen objects to be passed in):

```
private final AtomicReference<Screen> curScreen = ...;
...
public static boolean set(Screen nextScreen)
{
  mutex.lock(); // prevent multi-threading issues
  try
  {
    // ensure the provided screen is valid
    final Screen cur = curScreen.get();
    if (null == nextScreen || nextScreen.equals(cur)) return false;

    // atomically update the current screen reference
    if (!curScreen.compareAndSet(cur, nextScreen)) return false;

    // record the screen for back() operations and add it to the stage
    if (null != cur) screenStack.push(cur);
    stage.clear();
    stage.add(nextScreen);

    // grab any custom input processors from the stage and build an input handler
    final inputProcessors = nextScreen.getInputProcessors();
    final InputProcessor[] processors = inputProcessors.toArray(new InputProcessor[inputProcessors.size()+1]);
    processors [inputProcessors.length-1] = stage;

    // inform gdx of our new input target
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputMultiplexer(processors));

    return true;
  }
  catch (Throwable t) { Log.error(t); return false; }
  finally { mutex.unlock(); }
}
```

Please note the use of an `AtomicReference` *and* a custom `Mutex` object, which is due to more complex situations where efficiency can be gained. You can swap the `Mutex` for a `ReentrantLock` and convert the `AtomicReference` directly to a `Screen` for simpler applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this project: https://github.com/edesdan/libgdx-playground. Check it out to see if you can use it to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the instance of game using Gdx.app.getApplicationListener() casting it to Game. Furthermore, your code can become much cleaner, changing the setScreen method to:

```
public static void setScreen(Screen screen){
    if(currentScreen != null){
        currentScreen.dispose();
        System.out.println("Screen disposed");
    }
    currentScreen = screen;
    Game game = (Game)Gdx.app.getApplicationListener();
    game.setScreen(currentScreen);
}
```